# Overstayed then detained then came out from detention center then left voluntarily

Tags: united-kingdom, overstay

I gone into uk by study visa in the year of 2014.but I didn’t continue my studies.then I was overstayed for 3 years  then I was detained by home office.then I came out from detention center using solicitors.when I am in detention center I applied for asylum.but I couldn’t follow up the asylum process.then I left country voluntarily but January 05,2019.

Now whether can I re enter to uk by spouse visa?
My wife wants to study in uk
Can I go with her as a dependent 
Whether will I get visa or not?

Comment: It may also help if you tell us how long you’ve been married for

Comment: Can you tell us what your wife's nationality is, and what kind of visa she'll be applying for, if she needs one?

Comment: Your wife will be studying(not working) and you will be a dependent. How are you going to convince the UKBA ?

Comment: @DumbCoder Convince them of what? Since we don't know yet the nationality of his wife, we don't know what kind of visa OP will apply for, nor what its requirements are.